# range on different worksheet

Tags: combobox, range

I'm trying to load a combobox with an array (range) of labels from another worksheet. It works if I use "A4:PB4" in the range instead of the Cells method. Not sure why this doesn't work.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_GotFocus()

 Dim myArray As Variant
 lastcol = Worksheets("data").Range("A4").End(xlToRight).Column
 myArray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Worksheets("data").Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(4, lastcol)))
 With Me.ComboBox1
  .List = myArray
 End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Am I using the Cells within the Range properly?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub ComboBox1_GotFocus()

  Dim myArray As Variant

  lastcol = Worksheets("data").Range("A4").End(xlToRight).Column
  With Worksheets("data")
   Set SourceRng = .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(4, lastcol))
  End With
  myArray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(SourceRng)
  With Me.ComboBox1
   .List = myArray
  End With

 End Sub
```